# Reactive forms valueChanges how to watch just 2 fields[Angular2]

Tags: angular, rxjs

How can I watch just 2 fields of an Angular ReactiveForm? 
I have a form like the following:

```
this.filter = this.fb.group({
            text: ['', []],
            bankCountry: ['', []],
            bankCity: ['', []]
        });
```

How can I watch for changes related to just the last 2 fields?

Comment: You can use the rxjs `.filter()` operator - something like `this.fb.changes.filter(...).subscribe()`

Comment: I don't understand how that would work, you can't have a predicate to know which value changed or not...

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

1st, using combineLatest:

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest

```
Observable.combineLatest( this.text.valueChanges, this.bankCountry.valueChanges ).subscribe(respArr => {
     console.log(respArr); //this is array with responses from both observables
});
```

2nd, using filter:

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-filter

```
this.filter.valueChanges.filter((val) => /*filter predicate returning boolean*/).subscribe(val => {
    console.log(val);
});
```

Comment: About the predicate solution, how would you know which value changed or not, given that you don't want it to be triggered if value did not change?